# What happens if the first card is a Flip Card in UNO Flip?

Tags: uno-flip

I have a couple of questions regarding the use of the Flip card in UNO Flip.

1. What happens if the card turned over to start the Discard pile in the beginning of the game is a Flip card? Do we then start with the Dark Side or the Light Side?
2. What happens when we use a Flip card and then it reveals when flipped that the Discard pile's first card is a Wild Draw Color card?

Comment: Welcome to Board & Card games Q&A.
Your question contains of two different questions. Can you please split them in to separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

Since according to the [Mattel's UNO FLIP! rules](https://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/GDR44-English.pdf) there are no special instructions for a `Flip Card` turned over at the start of the game.

> NOTE: If any of the Action Cards (symbols) are turned over to start the DISCARD pile, see FUNCTIONS OF ACTION CARDS for special instructions.

If the card turned over to start the DISCARD pile is a `Flip Card` you should "flip over" all the cards and play the Dark Side.

> Flip Card – when you play this card, everything flips from the Light Side to the Dark Side. Once the Flip card has been played, flip over the Discard Pile (the card just played will now be on the bottom), then the Draw Pile, then everyone’s hands must flip to the other side...

Question 2 is answered here: 
[What to do after flipping the discard pile in Uno Flip?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/49745/what-to-do-after-flipping-the-discard-pile-in-uno-flip)

Answer (score 0):

If when you flip the discard pile and the first card is a wild draw color nothing happens according to the rules, only REGULAR wilds get reactivated.

If the first card taken from the draw pile to the discard pile is a flip card then you should flip to the opposite side i.e Light Side to Dark Side and vice versa.